# How to create a sample electron app that can integrate with three C++ libraries

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, electron

How to integrate 3 c++ libraries(fftw3, libsnd, zita resampler) into a simple electron app .......
I have created a simple Hello world App in Electron, further I'm looking for ways to integrate c++ libraries into this Helloworld app....
I would be thankful for Any help extended towards this.
below is the main.js code

```
    const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron') 
    const url = require('url') 
    const path = require('path')  

    let win  

    function createWindow() { 
    win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600}) 
    win.loadURL(url.format ({ 
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'), 
    protocol: 'file:', 
    slashes: true 
  })) 
}  
     app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

this is the index.html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <HTML>
    <head>
          <meta charset = "UTF-8">
          <title>Hello World!</title>
    </head>

          <body>
          <h1>Hello World!</h1>
              We are using node <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
              Chrome <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
              and Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: You should look into [Node.js C++ addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) and here some [examples](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples). After making a C++ Node addon that uses your C++ libraries, you can require it and use it in your Electron app's JavaScript code.

Comment: @aabuhijleh...i have looked into it as u suggested....but can we create a single addon for all three libraries?

Comment: There's no limit on the number of libraries you can use. You are basically building a C++ app and integrating it into Node.js. So to answer your question, yes, you can put all the logic and libraries you want in a single addon.

Comment: @aabuhijleh...I'm completely new to this concept...Any suggestions where I can learn How to create a native c++addon from scratch...particularly for these libraries....it would be a great help......